# POI: Append rows to existing workbook

Tags: apache-poi

Using XSSFWorkbook, is it possible to append rows to an existing sheet?  I am doing multiple writes (which was a PITA to solve due to a bug) and while I can write out new sheets multiple times, it does not appear that I can append.

What I am currently doing is the following:

1. Read sheet to my workbook.
2. Load workbook.
3. Append rows to workbook in memory
4. Write out again.

4 Does not appear to work, just ignores it completely!

I am aware that SXSSFWorkbook exists, but attempting to convert my existing XSSFWorkbook into a streaming workbook creates corruption upon write.

Is it possible to solve this concundrum?

**Update:  Changed code based on suggestion, but getting stream closed error.**

Code:  (The physical rows returns correctly, but nothing gets written out)

```
private void writeToSheetMultipleTimes(SXSSFWorkbook wb,
            ReportTemplateStructure appA, File wbFile)
    {

        Sheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);

        log.info("Attempting multi-write to sheet: " + sheet.getSheetName());
        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {

            Row row = sheet.getRow(i);

            if (row == null) {
               row = sheet.createRow(i);
            }
            Cell cell = row.getCell(0, Row.CREATE_NULL_AS_BLANK);



            cell.setCellValue("Written value:" + i);

            int numRows = sheet.getPhysicalNumberOfRows();

            log.info("Current row count: " + numRows);

            try{
                XSSFWorkbook xssfBook = (XSSFWorkbook)writeOutAndReadBack(wb);
                wb.dispose();

                wb = new SXSSFWorkbook(xssfBook);
            } catch (Exception e)
            {
                log.error("Unable to perform multiple write to same sheet", e);
            }
        }


    }

   public Workbook writeOutAndReadBack(Workbook wb) {
        if(!(wb instanceof SXSSFWorkbook)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Expected an instance of SXSSFWorkbook");
        }

        Workbook result;
        try {
            FileOutputStream baos = new FileOutputStream(streamingWorkBookFile);
            wb.write(baos);
            InputStream is = new FileInputStream(streamingWorkBookFile);
            result = new XSSFWorkbook(is);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: POI ships with a large number of unit tests that do what you describe and all pass without issue! I'd suggest you post some code showing what you're doing so we can try to spot your error

Comment: OK just edited it with code.  Thanks!

Comment: What OS are you on? Windows is notorious for being unhappy about you reading and writing to the same file without great care. Does it work if you write out to a different file?

Comment: I am on Windows, yes.  I think this is POI though.  Since I have a test method up above that opens up and the workbook and adds a sheet on every subsequent run - yet when I attempt to write to the same sheet, suddenly it explodes.   However in both methods I am writing/opening - so what is the difference?   Although I must say that in the first method I am *not* using SXSSFWorkbook.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You appear to be always making changes to Sheet 0, but you're calling `createRow` every time. This won't go well if there's already something there, eg on your second pass! You either need to add a new Sheet every time, or check if the Row is there with a call to `getRow(int)` first and only create if it is null.

If we look at your code snippet:

```
Sheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    Row row = sheet.createRow(i);
    Cell cell = row.createCell(0);
```

That should either be something like:

```
Sheet sheet = wb.createSheet();
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    Row row = sheet.createRow(i);
    Cell cell = row.createCell(0);
```

Or you should check first and only create missing rows/cells, eg

```
Sheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    Row row = sheet.getRow(i);
    if (row == null) {
       row = sheet.createRow(i);
    }
    Cell cell = row.getCell(0, Row.CREATE_NULL_AS_BLANK);
```

Comment: I also don't see the difference between the first and second block.  The third block I implemented, no avail.Created, but not written out.

Comment: Do you suppose this has anything to do with it?  The second I try to mess with writing in anyway, I get stream closed error.  Perhaps I am not writing correctly.   https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=53515

Comment: I'd suggest you look at one of the many POI unit tests that load a file up, make some changes and write them back out again. Compare them with your code, and see what you've done wrong. There are key differences between all 3 code snippets in my answer, and the answer attempts to explain them!

Comment: Gag, so in the second snippet I see you are creating a new sheet, but I cant do that.  I must append.   I have pulled the POI unit tests and am looking at the following:  TestSXSSFWorkbook.testAddToExistingWorkbook() - and they are basically doing the same thing as I am.  The only difference is that when they write out/read back, it is using a BOS instead of a FOS.   Since they are not actually writing anything to disk, how can we be sure that the actual file is being properly created.  I feel like I am seeing different..no?

Comment: You can only append to rows that aren't already there! TestSXSSFWorkbook.testAddToExistingWorkbook() only works because the rows it appends haven't previously been created. You can change that test to write to a temp file, and you should see it continue to work fine

Comment: Ahhh, I found the problem.  The code works.  The problem is that I was getting the sheet outside the loop!!!  The second I put it inside the loop, problem solved.  Oof, that was painful.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `getPhysicalNumberOfRows()` Method in `XSSFSheet` class to get last updated row number. Now create a new row by incrementing this value to append new data.