# How do I write many records to generate .xlsx file in batch?

Tags: java, excel, file, apache-poi, batch-processing

I am trying to write large no of records in a batch.

Here I have total 25 records and I am writing first 20 records then next 5 reocrds. But `FileOutputStream(filename,true)` is not appending to the previous written records.

```
package orginal;



public class ReadWriteExcelFile {

     static XSSFWorkbook wb = null;

static XSSFRow row = null;

/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {

    try {
        writeXLSFile();
    } catch (IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public static void writeXLSFile() throws IOException {
    String excelFileName = "C:\\Users\\RK\\Music\\500.xlsx";
    String sheetName = "Sheet1";

    wb = new XSSFWorkbook();
    XSSFSheet sheet = wb.createSheet(sheetName);

    FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(excelFileName, true);
    ArrayList arrList = new ArrayList();
    for (int i = 0; i < 25; i++) {
        arrList.add("Row ::" + i);
    }

    ArrayList aTemp1 = new ArrayList();
    int r = 0;

    // Writing first batch
    // iterating r number of rows
    for (r = 0; r < 20; r++) {
        createData(sheet, r);
    }
    writeRec(fileOut);

    for (int l = r; l < arrList.size(); l++) {
        aTemp1.add(arrList.get(l));
    }

    // Writing second batch for remaining records extra than the bacth size.
    for (int k = r; k < arrList.size(); k++) {
        createData(sheet, k);
    }
    fileOut = new FileOutputStream(excelFileName, true);
    writeRec(fileOut);

    System.out.println("done");
 }

 private static void createData(XSSFSheet sheet, int r) throws IOException {

    row = sheet.createRow(r);

    // iterating c number of columns
    for (int c = 0; c < 10; c++) {
        XSSFCell cell = row.createCell(c);
        cell.setCellValue("Cell " + r + " " + c);
    }
  }

  private static void writeRec(FileOutputStream fileOut) throws IOException {

    wb.write(fileOut);
    fileOut.flush();
    fileOut.close();
   }
```

}

Comment: You have to read in the existing file so that the workbook is in memory. Then, you create more rows in that memory model. Then, you write it out. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18794617/poi-append-rows-to-existing-workbook